# How to create CSS tag for radio button group

Tags: java, css, vaadin

[image]I'm using Vaadin 23 and tried adding CSS style (mentioned below) radio button. There is random alignment for options from selector as shown in the image. I want to make it left aligned. What should be exact CSS tag for this to add in Styles.css?

Comment: Looks not random, but centered. So maybe you should investigate, why centering is bleeding through from somewhere else? It's most likely not a "default".

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: start` for accessibility.

You can also use `text-align: left`, but it will force the alignment to left no matter what the page's language is

Comment: Should it be 
theme1 { text-align: left !important; } And then in Java

RadioButtonGroup<String> radioGroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
   radioGroup.addThemeName("theme1");

Comment: https://youtu.be/Swki9XXs9SA
here is the video I found on themes in Vaadin. Thanks

Comment: @DattaDhonde, if you inspect your radio button group via web DevTools you should be able to see the element and its attributes. choose your selector from there.